# Caching newest rows with H2

Tags: java, database, caching, h2

We have a relatively large table in a H2 database with up to 12 million rows. The table contains status information that a user needs to see on a web interface. The user is mainly only interested in the last couple of hundred / thousand entries, or entries over the last n days. Of course sometimes it will also be necessary to query all entries, but we can suppose that this happens seldomly and can take its time. Now our main problem is that we do not have a full blown server as target platform but a more embedded solution and with tables that size, the embedded system is taking a couple of seconds to respond and the web ui (with ajax etc.) feels sluggish.

To make the query faster we already added indexes, max_row_memory and caching. This makes the query impressively faster, but is still not in the range where we would like to be. 
As I understand, H2 flushes the cache of the table if an INSERT / UPDATE / DELETE is performed on the table. A large part of the application depends on the last n rows and I am searching for a way to always keep these n-rows in cache, so that if a SELECT query to get the last n rows is called, even after a previous INSERT, the rows are collected from the cache. 
As I did not find any solution in H2 directly, my first approach would be to implement the caching as a second level inside the application. The solution would be ok, but from a design point of view find it more appealing to have it inside H2. Anybody have an idea how I could solve this with H2?

Comment: Did you already look at the [H2 performance tips](http://h2database.com/html/performance.html#database_profiling)?

Answer (score 0):

H2 doesn't flush the cache on modification.
Your best bet is to run a profiler over your application to see where the time is going to.